# detecting disk encryption on android

Tags: android, security, encryption

Since Android SDK 3.0, users can choose to encrypt their entire disk which basically amounts to encrypting /data on a given device.  The option is presented in the phone preferences so I assumed it would be available for read by applications.  There's this DevicePolicyManager that looks like it has the information but am I to understand that an app must implement a receiver like [here](http://rootfs.wordpress.com/2010/09/09/android-make-your-application-a-device-administrator/)?  This doesn't really work for me since I don't want to explicitly manage the user's device and certainly don't want them to have to agree to such a thing for them to install my application.  Is there really not just some flag I can read somewhere to see if it's encrypted?

Comment: Why you want to know if it's encrypted anyway?

Comment: it's a long story but I need to provide services or not based on the answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> There's this DevicePolicyManager that looks like it has the information but am I to understand that an app must implement a receiver like here?

You could try using `getSystemService()` to get a `DevicePolicyManager`, then call `getStorageEncryptionStatus()`, and see if it works.

Comment: Great thanks, I'll give it a try.  PS big fan of your book.  Great coverage

Comment: Looks to work.  Thanks a lot.  Don't know how you find time to answer so many SO android questions but I'm glad you do!

Comment: @AndrewG: "Looks to work" -- that's cool. Unfortunately, the `DevicePolicyManager` is unclear on what methods can only be used by a `DeviceAdminReceiver` and which can be used by arbitrary other apps. "Don't know how you find time to answer so many SO android questions but I'm glad you do!" -- sleep is overratedzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzz. :-)