# Android Direct Boot issue while switching from credential to device storage

Tags: android

I have made an app to test direct boot. One activity which only store five preferences and boot receiver.

```
MainActivity.java
mSharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences("myapp_preferences", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
SharedPreferences.Editor editor = mSharedPreferences.edit();
editor.putString("pref1", "someStringPref1");
editor.putString("pref2", "someStringPref2");
editor.putString("pref3", "someStringPref3");
editor.putString("pref4", "someStringPref4");
editor.putString("pref5", "someStringPref5");
editor.commit();

final Map<String, ?> map = mSharedPreferences.getAll();
Log.d("BootReceiver", "map size: " + map.size());
```

Than a boot receiver code:

```
Context storageContext;
final Context deviceContext = context.createDeviceProtectedStorageContext();
if (!unlocked) {
    if (!deviceContext.moveSharedPreferencesFrom(context, "myapp_preferences")) {
        Log.w(TAG, "Failed to migrate shared preferences.");
    }
    storageContext = deviceContext;
} else {
    if (!context.moveSharedPreferencesFrom(deviceContext, "myapp_preferences")) {
        Log.w(TAG, "Failed to migrate shared preferences.");
    }
    storageContext = context;
}

mSharedPreferences = storageContext.getSharedPreferences("myapp_preferences", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
final Map<String, ?> map = mSharedPreferences.getAll();

Log.d(TAG, "intent action: " + intent.getAction());
Log.d(TAG, "map size: " + map.size());
```

My log

```
// activity started, five prefs successfully added
map size: 5
// device restarted, still unlocked -> direct boot mode
intent action: android.intent.action.LOCKED_BOOT_COMPLETED
map size: 0
// device unlocked (PIN screen lock used) -> credential encrypted storage
intent action: android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED
map size: 5
```

Why I cannot move prefs to device context (map size: 0)? An API bug? My device is buggy (file encryption is turned on, Nexus 5x, with patch from this October)? Or most likely, am I missing something?

PS Missing android-directboot tag.

**Update**
Same behaviour with Nexus 6p, for both 7.0 (app compiled with `compileSdkVersion 24`) and 7.1.1 (`compileSdkVersion 24&25`) OS version.

**Update #2**

```
if (Intent.ACTION_LOCKED_BOOT_COMPLETED.equals(action)) {
    unlocked = false;
} else if (Intent.ACTION_BOOT_COMPLETED.equals(action)) {
    unlocked = true;
}
```

Comment: Direct boot is still in a pre-release state, so I have not given it much attention. What is `unlocked`?

Comment: See my Update #2. How do you know that it is in pre-release? There is no such information on official page.

Comment: File encryption is pre-release IIRC, which should mean that direct boot is pre-release by extension. I agree with GoneUp. I think the idea is that you keep your data in one spot, with the migration being a one-time thing.

Comment: One sub-question, are you aware how to detect FBE? One of your [answers](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13298299/detecting-disk-encryption-on-android) shows how to detect FDE, but I would like to do migration only for N devices with FBE on.

Comment: I haven't played with it yet, and I do not remember a mechanism for detection off the top of my head. Sorry!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From my understanding you saving your prefs to the normal user locked storage and trying to move it from there to the device locked storage at boot time. That won't work since at boot time the user storage is locked. 
You need to save your shared prefs directly to the device storage context and use the migration procedure only in the upgrade from the older devices case.

See this [google example](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-DirectBoot/blob/737ab9a214debbf3c940360b834077ccc3035ff3/Application/src/main/java/com/example/android/directboot/alarms/AlarmStorage.java) for a correct handling of direct boot.

Comment: Not sure that it is idea to store it permanently to device protected storage, but this answer definitely shows me the mistake I've made in code.